# How to exclude MessageHandler delegate swagger ui?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger

I have recently included swagger to my web api, when I try to access the `http://localhost:63080/swagger` it will bring up json as `{"Errors":[],"Data":null}`, this is due to delegation handler, How can I exclude the messagehandler for swagger request?

Comment: I have registered handler in Application_Start `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new ResponseWrappingHandler());`

Comment: any one web api or swagger experts?

Comment: I posted a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63501767/swagger-isnt-working-in-owin-startup-web-api-c-sharp/63524950#63524950) for a problem similar to this.