# Swagger isn't working in OWIN Startup Web API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, owin, swagger-ui

I've implemented Swagger in the OWIN startup.cs file in my Web API, but when I try to open Swagger UI page it says **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found**

URL to check Swagger UI: https://localhost:5001/swagger

Here is my implementation, please help me what I'm missing.

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   {
     app.Map("/api", map => { ConfigureApiArea(map); });
   }

   private void ConfigureApiArea(IAppBuilder map)
   {
            var config = CreateTypedConfiguration<BaseApiController>();

            //Json Settings
            JsonFormatterSettings(config);

            ConfigureAutofac(config, map);
            ConfigureOAuth(map);

            config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "Paging-Headers,X-Error"));
            map.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            config.EnsureInitialized();


            map.UseWebApi(config);
   }

   private HttpConfiguration CreateTypedConfiguration<TBaseController>() where TBaseController : IHttpController
   {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerTypeResolver), new 
            TypedHttpControllerTypeResolver<TBaseController>());
            config.EnableSwagger();
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new TypedDirectRouteProvider<TBaseController>());
            return config;
   }

}
```

**SwaggerExtensions.cs**

```
 public static class SwaggerExtensions
    {
        public static HttpConfiguration EnableSwagger(this HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
        {
            httpConfiguration
                .EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "MyWebAPI"))
                .EnableSwaggerUi();

            return httpConfiguration;
        }
    }
```

**MyController.cs**

```
public class MyController : BaseApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("orders/{orderId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetOrder([FromUri]string orderId) {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**BaseApiController.cs**

```
 public class BaseApiController : ApiController { }
```

Comment: Have you tried `https://localhost:5001/api/swagger` ?

Comment: Yes I did https://localhost:5001/api/swagger and also https://localhost:5001/api/swagger/ui but no still same 404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was in fact `https://localhost:5001/api/swagger` as @Dai suggested, the reason it was not working was because of the custom `MessageHandlers` inside the method `ConfigureAutofac(config, map)` (not shown in the code by OP) were not handling the requests with path with `/swagger` in them.

`MessageHandler` code inside the method `ConfigureAutofac(config, map)` omitted:

```
private void ConfigureAutofac(HttpConfiguration config, IAppBuilder app)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();    
    
    //code omitted for brevity ...

    //Register Web API controllers.
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .InstancePerRequest();

    //Register the Autofac filter provider.
    builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

    //Register the Autofac model binder provider.
    builder.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();

    //code omitted for brevity ...
    
    var container = builder.Build();

    //Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
    config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    config.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new ApiDelegatingHandler());
    config.MessageHandlers.Insert(1, new ActivityLogHandler());

    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
}
```

The only change required in the custom `MessageHandler` was to handle this, as below:

```
public class ApiDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.Contains("/swagger")) 
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        //code omitted for brevity ...
    }
}
```

Comment: One note to add here: the Contains() method is case sensitive, so if your application joins swagger by ".../Swagger" for example, this won't work well enough, you need to convert it to lowercase: `if (request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.ToLower().Contains("/swagger")) { ... }`